# my facebook send button distort in ie7. how to solve this issue?

Tags: facebook, api

here is how its look in ie7..
[image]
here is those code i type in my sites.
    http://jsfiddle.net/D2wXx/

hi, facebook send button is distort in ie7, any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have IE7 to check with, so if you could go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/ and see if it distorts there too.  If so, then it's a defect you'll need to log at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs.

Comment: i think fb pages using chrome frame. so cannot test  properly  with official pages

Comment: huh? I'm not sure I understand your response.  Did you get a chance to test http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/ in IE7?

Comment: http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/
in facebook, they use something like this. to solve ie layout problem. but their official page no distort at all.

Comment: hi , its not really answer my question, my team still finding for answer for this issue.

Comment: What was the results of trying the login button at the link?

Comment: I think at this point, you have a reproducible bug you should file with http://developers.facebook.com/bugs.  Sometimes the answer to a question is "it's a bug".  Can you file one and then report back here with the bug number so others who might come across your question can see that it's a bug?