# How to fix IE7 "Facebook Send Button" layout running?

Tags: css, facebook, internet-explorer, api, facebook-like

I'm unable to display the whole Facebook "Send" Button in IE7. 
However, It's working fine in Chrome, Mozilla, IE9, IE8.

The Send button layout become:-
[image]

my HTML code as:-

```
<div class="facebook_wrapper">
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=119279021491995&amp;xfbml=1"</script>
<fb:send font=" " href="http://www.google.com.my/"></fb:send>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your css for `facebook_wrapper` ?

Comment: .facebook_wrapper {margin-bottom: 7px;}

Comment: try setting: `display:block;width:200px;height:25px;` for the `.facebook_wrapper` div

Comment: also, in the code you posted, change `xbfml=1"</script>` to `xbfml=1"></script>"`

Comment: i facing the same problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908455/my-facebook-send-button-distort-in-ie7-how-to-solve-this-issue,

Comment: @Alaways21: Just post your complete HTML markup and also CSS. Maybe a JSFiddle or a link to a live site would be great help and lets see why it can't be fixed. It's no use argueing to not to support IE7 since that is your requirement. I am sure people here with good expertise can find a workaround.

Comment: @Dementic: Actually, i had implement your suggestion.
`.facebook_wrapper {display:block;width:200px;height:25px;}`
change `xbfml=1"</script>` into `xbfml=1"></script>"`
but the button still display the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, lets see if I can get this right for you, since you aren't dropping IE7 support.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
     <div class="facebook_wrapper"></div>
     <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=119279021491995&amp;xfbml=1"</script>
     <fb:send font=" " href="http://www.google.com.my/"></fb:send>
</div>
```

P.S. I have no way to test this, because the developer tools on IE9 don't show a problem when trying to view it as IE7. Hope this fixes it!

*EDIT* - If the previous doesn't work, it would appear that this problem could possibly be due to other styling that is still be applied.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into similar issues with IE 7 truncating the like button.  After digging into the embedded css I found the culprit to be a class that sets width to 1px.

There is a class .pluginButton BUTTON that you will want to look for.  Write a conditional override in your css for IE 7 and adjust that width property accordingly.

I am testing it out now and will post back.

Comment: Was this ever confirmed as the source of an issue? I am currently having the same problem and none of the above or below fixes managed to help. I was curious about this though.

Answer (score 0):

My advice, drop IE 7 support. Google has already dropped support for it and Microsoft is planning on making previous versions of IE update to a minimum of IE 8.

Comment: Bad advice, even due ie7 is dying slowly, there is no reason to collectivly punish your users.

Comment: If this would have been an option for him, he probably would not come here and ask how to fix the issue ;-)

Comment: The fact that Microsoft is getting rid of it should be a reason to punish those users that still insist on using that nasty browser. Also, I feel as though Google sets a lot of standards now-a-days and as big of a company that they are, that's punishing more users than this guy has.

EDIT - I also understand that he probably would have not posted if he thought about dropping IE7. But to down vote a person for giving his opinion that is a very common and highly agreed upon opinion in web coders is stupid and discouraging people to even try to be helpful.

Comment: i work in casino affiliate company, each user that i will `kick` out of the site because of ie7, can cost us dearly. BAD ADVICE IS BAD.

Comment: i appologize english is not my native language, i do know 3 other languages perfectly... but, that is not the discussion is it?

Comment: its not that your english is bad, its the point that you purposely put the idiotic statement "BAD ADVICE IS BAD". But the point of this discussion is you down vote me for simply adding a general consensus of web developers around the world.

Comment: its a pitty you start in this community with anger... if your answer is not good enough, you should learn from others. in my specific case, your advice could cost the company i work for a great deal of money. surely if it was your company that would not be accepted by you.

Comment: I start in this community with anger because people: A) Don't take into consideration that you are new and just close posts with no reason, when someone was in the middle of helping. B) Down vote for opinions that are legitimate among millions of coders. If it was my company it would be accepted, in fact I have many websites that now have dropped IE 7. Sure your company will lose a tiny amount of money from those customers. As of last year IE7 was only used by 9% of internet users. I'm sure you would be fine without that tiny percentage.

Comment: i would suggest taking it easy. when i started here, i had the same problem, people were closing my posts and down voting me. just smile and learn from your mistakes. thats what i did :) got to go to work, so i wish you a great day and welcome to this community.

Comment: @dementic I made no mistake, unless you count adding legitimate advice a mistake in which case EVERYONE is making a mistake.

Comment: Hahaha. Microsoft has done it again. Make people fight over mistakes that Microsoft has themselevs made.

Comment: @MichaelStramel - got to the office, hypoteticly asked my boss about that 9%. he said as follows "well, since we are making 100k a month, 9% would be 9k, which means, i cannot afford you anymore, so pack your bags and leave." - you still think 9% is not important ?

Comment: @Dementic yes I still do. The number that would be drawn to your company is probably just a tiny fraction of that 9%. I understand that your company makes money off of their users, but that amount of money is still most likely not going to affect the company. IF it is really that big of a deal, for IE7 write a script to tell them to upgrade their browser if they are running under IE 8. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

after having a look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/

it seems your code is either very old, or wrong.

put this somewhere in the body ( preferably right after the `body` tag )

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and put this where you want the send button to show up:
`<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://example.com"></div>`

or, if you want XFBML, same script after the body, but also:

`<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">` <--- your `<html>` tag

and `<fb:send href="http://example.com"></fb:send>` where you want the button.

Comment: I had implement the script, but the Facebook send button still display as half only.

Comment: can you show us a live page with the problem ? most of the chances you have a css rules that overrides the tag.